# 追尾するためのプログラムのエラーが解決できません。

Tags: c++, c, opencv

環境
Windows10　64bit
VS2017 
opencv_contrib-3.4.1

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/tracking/tracker.hpp>
#include <opencv2/tracking/tldDataset.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int tracker_init(cv::Ptr<cv::TrackerMedianFlow> &tracker, cv::Rect2d &rect)
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "CAN'T OPEN CAMERA." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::namedWindow("Select face");

    while (true)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "FAILD TO READ A FRAME" << std::endl;
            cv::destroyAllWindows();
            break;
        }

        cv::imshow("Select face", frame);

        switch (cv::waitKey(1))
        {
        case 'q':
            return -1;
        case 't':
            rect = cv::selectROI("tracker", frame);
            tracker->init(frame, rect);
            cv::destroyAllWindows();
            return 1;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cv::Ptr<cv::TrackerMedianFlow> tracker = cv::TrackerMedianFlow::create();
    cv::Rect2d roi;

    if (tracker_init(tracker, roi) == -1)
    {
        /*
        * 初期化に失敗
        */
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0);
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "CAN'T OPEN CAMERA." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while (cv::waitKey(1) != 'q')
    {
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
        {
            break;
        }

        //更新
        tracker->update(frame, roi);

        //結果表示
        cv::rectangle(frame, roi, color, 1, 1);

        cv::imshow("tracker", frame);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

をVS2017でビルドしようとしたところ以下のエラーが出ました。

```
1>------ ビルド開始: プロジェクト:追尾システム, 構成:Release x64 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>Source.cpp(39): error C2039: 'selectROI': 'cv' のメンバーではありません。
1>  C:\opencv_contrib-3.4.1\modules\tracking\include\opencv2/tracking/tldDataset.hpp(47): note: 'cv' の宣言を確認してください
1>Source.cpp(39): error C3861: 'selectROI': 識別子が見つかりませんでした
========== ビルド: 0 正常終了、1 失敗、0 更新不要、0 スキップ ==========
```

どうにか解決法を見つけているのですが困っています。

Comment: エラーメッセージの意味は理解されているでしょうか？ https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/dd5/highgui_8hpp.html

Comment: 関係ありそうなQ&A https://teratail.com/questions/122159